# Как сделать передачу переменной в PHP через /?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как можно на сайте настроить передачу переменной метором GET не так `http://site.com?var=value`, а так `http://site.com/value` ?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://www.phpinfo.su/articles/practice/chpu_na_php.html), например, посмотрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого редакритуйте .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ request.php?route=page&slag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Это перенаправит выполнение скрипту ***request.php*** с *GET* параметрами *route* и *slag*.